# How to temporarily withhold relayout while adding views to Android app

Tags: android, layout, view

I have an app where views are added dynamically at run time. This is done using `addView()` to the layout container where the views have to go. It works fine.

However sometimes all the existing views need to be removed and a new lot added all in one go.

I am assuming that any call to `addView()` results in a layout request propagating right up the tree. The problem with this is that it would result in a relayout on every addition of a view, whereas it would be much more efficient to add them all, then do one relayout.

I could do this much more efficiently by reusing views, only removing those that are superfluous, only adding new when necessary etc, but it would be simpler and neater just not to relayout until finished.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each modification of the view hierarchy (`addView()`/`removeView()`) does propagate a layout *request*, but that's just a flag that is set. A full layout pass does not occur until a later scheduled time, based on the screen refresh rate.

In other words, you do not have to do anything special. In a given routine, you may modify the view hierarchy as much as you see fit (completely replacing all `Views`, if you want), and this will only generate 1 layout pass in response.

Some `Views` may get multiple calls to `onMeasure()`, but that is normal behavior that is associated with a single layout pass.